# Resolve name by inode in current direcory

Tags: perl, awk, solaris, ksh

How can I resolve the name by the given inode in the current directory in the following script that prints all filenames of symlinks pointing to a specified file that is passed as an argument to the script. The list should be sorted by ctime.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

IFS="`printf '\n\t'`"

USAGE="usage: symlink.sh <file>"

get_ctime() {
    perl -se 'use File::stat; $file=lstat($filename); print $file->ctime' -- -filename="$1"
}

stat_inode() {
    perl -se 'use File::stat; $file=stat($filename); if (defined $file) { print $file->ino; }' -- -filename="$1"
}

lstat_inode() {
    perl -se 'use File::stat; $file=lstat($filename); if (defined $file) { print $file->ino; }' -- -filename="$1"
}


if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "$USAGE"
    exit 1
fi

FILE_NAME="$1"
FILE_INODE=$(stat_inode "$FILE_NAME")

if [ ! -e "$FILE_NAME" ]; then
    echo "no such file \"$FILE_NAME\""
    exit 1
fi


for LINK in ./* ./.[!.]*  ;do
    if [ -L "$LINK" ]; then
    TARGET_INODE=$(stat_inode "$LINK")
    if [ ! -z "$TARGET_INODE" ]; then
        if [ "$FILE_INODE" -eq "$TARGET_INODE" ]; then
        echo $(get_ctime "$LINK") $(lstat_inode "$LINK");
        fi
    fi
    fi
done | sort -nk1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Basically, I'd like to pipe awk to some kind of lookup function like this: | awk ' ' | lookup

I'd really appreciate if someone suggested a more elegant way to accomplish the task.

OS: SunOS 5.10
Shell: KSH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -inum 2883399 
./.jshintrc
$
```

or:

```
$ echo 2883399 | xargs -IX find . -maxdepth 1 -inum X
./.jshintrc
$
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. (But -maxpath is not implemented in find I'm using. What were you trying to accomplish with this -maxdepth 1 ?)

Comment: -maxdepth limits find's search and will make it faster.  Mid you, with an inode in hand it doesn't need to do much searching so the speedup may be non-existent.  If it works without it, party on. :-)